# How do I parse the XML document using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse an RSS feed from Digital Trends. I am unable to get the attributes. For example, I need to get the URL of the image inside the `<enclosure>` tag.

The XML file is:

```
<item>   
  <title>   
    Xbox One returns to Best Buy with five new holiday bundles
  </title>
  <link>
    http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/xbox-one-returns-best-buy-five-new-holiday-    bundles/
  </link>
  <pubDate>Thu, 12 Dec 2013 23:59:20 +0000</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="http://icdn7.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft-xbox-one-review-system-v2-100x100-c.jpg" length="0" type="image/png"/>
</item>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you expecting us to write it for you? [Nokogiri's tutorials](http://nokogiri.org) cover this in enough detail to make this an easy job. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: This is RSS. Don't parse it by hand. Use an RSS parser.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584361/how-do-i-parse-xml-using-nokogiri-and-split-a-node-value/8584606#8584606

Comment: In my experience, even an RSS parser can't parse real-world RSS, because it is such an abused spec. Toss in ATOM and RDF and it requires a hand-rolled parser. Start with a canned one to see if it works, but don't be surprised if it fails with anything beyond a simple feed.

Comment: @theTinMan  `require 'rubygems'`
`require 'nokogiri'`
`require 'open-uri'`
`doc=Nokogiri::XML(open('http://www.digitaltrends.com/feed/'))`
`doc.xpath('//item').each do |t|`
  `p t.at_xpath('./title').content`
  `p t.at_xpath('./description').content`
  `p t.at_xpath('./pubDate').content`
 `p t.at_css('enclosure')`

`end`

Comment: Updated the code snipet @MarkThomas

Comment: @theTinMan I've had no problems parsing feeds with [SimpleRSS](https://github.com/cardmagic/simple-rss). It handles even invalid XML (RSS and Atom), and you can configure it to handle non-standard extra elements etc.

Comment: check or up the helpful answers

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/
I also found ox is 5 times faster than nokogiri while reading a large xml.
Plus I have a wrapper written which simply allow you to search through large xml using ox, allows you to iterate with specified element.
https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 1):

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(...)
item = xml.xpath('//item')
item.at('enclosure')['url']
```

or

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(...)
item = xml.xpath('//item')
item.at('enclosure').attr('url')
```

The first example returns a String, the second example returns a `Nokogiri::XML::Attr` instance representing the string value.

Of course, replace

```
Nokogiri::XML(...)
```

with a proper document parsing, according to the source of your XML document.

You may want to read the article [Searching an HTML / XML Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html). More details are also available in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) API documentation.

Comment: Be careful with `item.at('enclosure').first`. `at` returns a single Node, not a NodeSet, and a Node doesn't have a `first` method. `item.search('enclosure').first` would work though.

Comment: My fault, I originally used `css` than changed it to `at`. I fixed the code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@doc.xpath("//enclosure")[0].attr("url")`, assuming you have the document loaded into `@doc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML IO.read( 'file.xml' )
e = doc.css( 'enclosure' )
puts e.attr( 'url' )
```